Observing a particle
We say that there is uncertainty in position when we observe a particle. But first i want to know in detail about how do we observe a particles position and momentum. Suppose we know that an electron is present in a box then what exactly people do to measure it's position and momentum and what data do they observe and how do they analyse the data to tell position of the electron?

Does this answer your question? What exactly do we observe in particle accelerators that we have named "particles"?

@hft it says that we observe dots in a position detector . So at a particular instance of time we determine it's position completely . So there is no uncertainty in position at a particular time?
